# How can I retrieve only one product from a Magento collection?

Tags: magento

I have a collection, which contains only one product. How I can get this product without using a "foreach' cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$collection->getFirstItem()` to retrieve the first item from a collection.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so simply really :)